# Parse airport taxiway labels

Tags: c#, regex

I'm in the midst of writing a c# method that translates airport taxiways from their orignial format to a written out version...so for example:

`AA` would be written as `ALPHA ALPHA`

`F1` as `FOXTROT 1`

Take a look at the Los Angeles airport diagram for more examples: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8614gp41dwnwvsm/klax.PDF

This is what I have so far:

```
public static string ParseTaxiway(string taxiway)
{
    string twy = "";
    var alpha = Regex.Match(taxiway, "([A-Z]){1,2}");
    var alphanum = Regex.Match(taxiway, "([A-Z])([1-9])");

    // do we have an alpha character only taxiway?
    if(alpha.Success)
    {
        switch(alpha.Groups[1].Value)
        {
            case "A":
                twy = "ALPHA";
                break;
            case "B":
                twy = "BRAVO";
                break;
            case "C":
                twy = "CHARLIE";
                break;
            case "D":
                twy = "DELTA";
                break;
            case "E":
                twy = "ECHO";
                break;
            case "F":
                twy = "FOXTROT";
                break;
            case "G":
                twy = "GOLF";
                break;
            case "H":
                twy = "HOTEL";
                break;
            case "I":
                twy = "INDIA";
                break;
            case "J":
                twy = "JULIET";
                break;
            case "K":
                twy = "KILO";
                break;
            case "L":
                twy = "LIMA";
                break;
            case "M":
                twy = "MIKE";
                break;
            case "N":
                twy = "NOVEMBER";
                break;
            case "O":
                twy = "OSCAR";
                break;
            case "P":
                twy = "PAPA";
                break;
            case "Q":
                twy = "QUEBEC";
                break;
            case "R":
                twy = "ROMEO";
                break;
            case "S":
                twy = "SIERRA";
                break;
            case "T":
                twy = "TANGO";
                break;
            case "U":
                twy = "UNIFORM";
                break;
            case "V":
                twy = "VICTOR";
                break;
            case "W":
                twy = "WHISKEY";
                break;
            case "X":
                twy = "XRAY";
                break;
            case "Y":
                twy = "YANKEE";
                break;
            case "Z":
                twy = "ZULU";
                break;
        }
    }

    // taxiway with letter and number; A1, F5, B6, etc
    if(alphanum.Success)
    {
        switch (alphanum.Groups[1].Value)
        {
            case "A":
                twy = "ALPHA " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "B":
                twy = "BRAVO " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "C":
                twy = "CHARLIE " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "D":
                twy = "DELTA " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "E":
                twy = "ECHO " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "F":
                twy = "FOXTROT " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "G":
                twy = "GOLF " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "H":
                twy = "HOTEL " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "I":
                twy = "INDIA " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "J":
                twy = "JULIET " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "K":
                twy = "KILO " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "L":
                twy = "LIMA " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "M":
                twy = "MIKE " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "N":
                twy = "NOVEMBER " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "O":
                twy = "OSCAR " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "P":
                twy = "PAPA " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "Q":
                twy = "QUEBEC " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "R":
                twy = "ROMEO " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "S":
                twy = "SIERRA " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "T":
                twy = "TANGO " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "U":
                twy = "UNIFORM " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "V":
                twy = "VICTOR " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "W":
                twy = "WHISKEY " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "X":
                twy = "XRAY " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "Y":
                twy = "YANKEE " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
            case "Z":
                twy = "ZULU " + alphanum.Groups[2].Value);
                break;
        }
    }

    return twy;
}
```

The issue I'm having with this is if I have a taxiway labeled `AA`, it will only return `ALPHA`. Taxiways are limited to one or two letters long **or** one letter with one number (1-9). R, AA, AC, D1, ZZ, etc...so there are many combinations.

If someone could guide me on the right path to properly creating this parsing method, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach tries to cut down on the amount of boilerplate code.

```
public static class Taxiway
{
    private static Dictionary<char, string> lookup =
        new string[]
        {
            "ALPHA",
            "BRAVO",
            "CHARLIE",
            ...
            "ZULU"
        }
        .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Select(n => n.ToString()))
        .ToDictionary(s => s[0]);

    public static string Parse(string s)
    {
        if (s == null || s.Length < 1 || s.Length > 2
            || !s.All(c => lookup.ContainsKey(c))
            || !char.IsLetter(s[0]))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid taxiway.", "s");
        }
        return string.Join(" ", s.Select(c => lookup[c]));
    }
}
```

`Taxiway.Parse("W5")` will give you `"WHISKEY 5"`,
`Taxiway.Parse("C")` will give you `"CHARLIE"`,
`Taxiway.Parse("CA")` will give you `"CHARLIE ALPHA"`, etc.

It will only accept strings of one of the following forms:
`"{A-Z}"`, `"{A-Z}{A-Z}"`, `"{A-Z}{1-9}"`.

Aside: `ParseX` suggests a method that converts a `string` to a `X`. You might want to consider a different name.

Comment: Works great...however, the issue I have now (which I should have included in my original question), was if I have the taxiway in a sentence. For example `TWY C5 CLSD. TWY C10 AND TWY C5 CLSD`...which I want to be rewritten as `TWY CHARLIE 5 CLSD. TWY CHARLIE 10 AND TWY CHARLIE 5 CLSD`

Comment: @Zach 1. Pull the negation of the `if` condition out into a separate IsMatch method that takes a string and returns a book. 2. Split your sentence on space characters. 3. For each split string, if it IsMatch, replace it with Parse. 4. Concatenate the split strings with spaces to reconstruct the sentence.

Comment: @Zach Also your example references "C10" which does not match your specifications.

Comment: @Timonthy, I am sorry. I guess it was too late last night for me to work :-P. So, taxiways can have numbers larger than 10. `A21`, `AA`, `A1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the key/value mappings into a dictionary and loop through the input string character by character to get the word and create the final output.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, string>();

dictionary.Add('A', "Alpha");
// and so on..

public static string ParseTaxiway(string taxiway)
{
 string finalValue = "";

 foreach (var character in taxiway)
 {
  finalValue += dictionary[character] +" ";
 }

 return finalValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These guys talk about doing something that PHP has called strtr().  Basically you feed it a string and it returns a translation of characters.  It's really handy for this type of stuff:

http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/equalvilent-method-strtr-functon-php-541398.html

Otherwise, you might try using an ordered dictionary for all your letter /number dictionaries in a single dimension like so:

```
OrderedDictionary alphas = new OrderedDictionary();

// add your alphas
alphas.Add("A", "ALPHA");
alphas.Add("B", "BRAVO");
..etc
```

Then reference them by index to build your string (alpha is your regex single character value)

```
twy = alphas[alpha] + alphanum.Groups[2].Value;
```

For what you're trying to do, build a string, this method will save some code and requires no business logic.

Comment: I realized that you also have to worry about if your 2nd character is numeric or an alphanumeric character.  I'm not sure how you're determining if you have a 2nd character but you could do a simple boolean like `if(second_character_is_numeric_condition) { alphas[alpha] + alphanum.Groups[2].Value; } else { twy = alphas[first_char_reference] + alphas[second_char_reference]; } `.  Anyway, hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the codes and translations in a dictionary, then use LINQ to translate each character:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    { 'A', "ALPHA" },
    { 'B', "BRAVO" },
    ...
    { 'F', "FOXTROT" },
    ...
    { '1', "1" },
    { '2', "2" },
    ...
};

var code = "AA";

var translation = string.Join(" ", code.Select(c => dict[c]));
```

Output:

```
ALPHA ALPHA   // AA

FOXTROT 1     // F1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stub

```
enum MyEnum
{
    ALPHA,
    BRAVO
}
String taxiNo= "AB";
String convertedString = "";
if(taxiNo.Length == 0)
{
    // throw exception
}
else
    convertedString = ((MyEnum)((int)(taxiNo.ToCharArray()[0])-65)).ToString();
if(taxiNo.Length == 2)
{
    int justForCheck;
    if(!int.TryParse(taxiNo.Substring(1,1),out justForCheck))
        convertedString += " " + ((MyEnum)((int)(taxiNo.ToCharArray()[1])-65)).ToString();
    else
        convertedString += " " + taxiNo[1].ToString();
}
```